# ChromeVox, input range gets wrong step value. It jumps to max value

Tags: html, accessibility, voice-recognition

I am trying to make an input type="range" to work correctly with ChromeVox.
Here the issue:

- if I click the right arrow key to move forward, it jumps directly to the max value that in my example is 100
- if i click the left arrow key to go back but it steps 2 values per time even if the attribute min="1"

This happen just when ChromeVox is enabled, anybody experienced the same issue?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function outputUpdate(newValue) { 
                    document.querySelector('#volume').value = newValue;

                    var handle = event.target;
                    handle.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", newValue.toString()); 
                    }
            </script>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="fader">Volume</label>
    <input type="range" id="fader" 
            min="1" max="100" 
            step="1" 
            role="slider" 
            aria-valuemin="1" 
            aria-valuemax="100" 
            oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
    <output for="fader" id="volume">50</output>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE
I open an issue
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=938321
they won't fix it

Comment: I would strongly suggest rewording your question to "How can this be solved?" or something similar, since "Anybody experiencing the same issue?" is not a valid question type on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have the same problem. I suspect this is a bug with ChromeVox. The navigation works fine, but doesn't work properly with Vox enabled.

Comment: I open an issues 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=938321
they won't fix it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with next code. I`m using React, so, sorry for non-vanilla synaxis.

```
const onChange= (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
};
const onKeyDown = (event) => {
    const { key } = event;
    if (['ArrowRight', 'ArrowUp'].includes(key) && value < max) {
        event.preventDefault();

        setValue(value + step);
    }

    if (['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowDown'].includes(key) && value > min) {
        event.preventDefault();

        setValue(value - step);
    }
};
```

- setValue - means set value to input by appropriate way for your project.

```
<input
    min={min}
    max={max}
    step={step}
    type="range"
    value={value}
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
    onChange={onChange}
/>
```

It is important:

1. to member that onKeyDown is called before onChange
2. to call event.preventDefault(); only in case of navigation key, otherwise onChange will be called after onKeyDown handler and input would not work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same issue you found but I had an issue were incrementing the slider value jumped it to its max value.

Mine was due to a parsing error. Adding 1 to a string gave a weird result which was greater than the max slider value.

This resulted in the weird max jump:

```
sliderElement.value = sliderElement.value + 1;
```

This fixed it:

```
sliderElement.value = parseInt(sliderElement.value) + 1;
```